# Hide untranslated djangocms menu items in Aldryn with hide_untranslated doesnt seem to work

Tags: django-cms, divio

I would like `show_menu` template tag to only output menu items that belong to pages that have a translation in the current language.

However I have been unable to set djangocms CMS_LANGUAGES in `settings.py` of my Aldryn project accordingly, using the `hide_untranslated` property. Aldryn seems to ignore that setting.

Also, I read from the djangocms documentation that `hide_untranslated` is `True` by default: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/master/docs/reference/configuration.rst#hide_untranslated

Is it possible that Aldryn overwrites `CMS_LANGUAGES`? I am also asking because one can set the CMS languages in the Aldryn control panel which is possibly incompatible with settting `CMS_LANGUAGES` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The following setting works in Aldryn to hide untranslated pages in all configured languages.

`CMS_LANGUAGES['default'] = {
        'fallbacks': ['en'],
        'redirect_on_fallback': False,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': True,
    }`